# How to test a method that uses IEnumerable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, ienumerable

I'm trying to test a method that takes in an object that has an `IEnumerable<string>` property but don't know how to make that work in a test.

I've tried Mocking the property which failed because the object isn't mocked.

The method I want to test looks like:

```
myMethod(MyObject object)
```

The object  has the property:

```
public IEnumerable<string> EnumProperty { get; set; }
```

I'm sure(and hoping) I'm just missing something really obvious.

Comment: Please add your test code.

Comment: `IEnumerable<>` is implemented by all generic collections *and* arrays. You can store any string collection to `MyObject.EnumProperty` , eg a `string[]` or `List<string>` before passing it to `myMethod`

Comment: I can´t see where you mock **anything**.

Comment: If `EnumProperty` is the only issue, you don't need to mock it at all

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are absolutely right. Knew i was completely missing it :)

Answer (score 0):

I was definitely overthinking it. As Panagiotis Kanavos quite rightly pointed out, all i needed was to make it as a `new string[]`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could use `Enumerable.Empty<string>()` or `Array.Empty<string>()` instead.